# How to overwrite a certain branch with master

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have two branches `dev` and `master`. I want my dev branch to be completely overwritten by `master` branch as I know master is latest. How can I do that using TortoiseGit UI?

I tried to do merge using TortoiseGit but that would result in many conflicts.

Please let me know the answers in Tortoise GIT only as I am only using UI and not familiar with actual GIT commands.

Comment: `git branch -D dev` && `git checkout -b dev`

Comment: How can I do this in Tortoise GIT?

Comment: you probably can't do advanced things like this in the GUI

Answer (score 7):

> Disclaimer : this is not a TortoiseGit solution, but a CLI one, I hope
>   it'll help someone anyway.

Since nobody suggested it already, let's also note this quite simple way to do it :

```
git branch -f dev master
```

It's a short way to set the first given ref (here : dev) to the same point where the second ref (here : master) is currently pointing to. (As a sidenote, they're not "linked" in any way after this command, and stay independant for all intents and purposes.)

As it rewrites the history of branch dev, if it has a remote counterpart you'll have to push it with force :

```
git checkout dev
git push -f origin HEAD
```

**In any case, if you happen to have other people working with you on that branch, any of the solutions here are ways to rewrite history so be sure to discuss this with them beforehand!**

Answer (score 2):

In TortoiseGit you have several options depending on your scenario:

1. You are on the `dev` branch: Go to the log dialog, open the context menu on the master branch entry and select "Reset to" and choose "hard".
2. You are not on the `dev` branch: Create a new branch with the name `dev` choose the `master` branch as origin and select "Override branch if exists" (or go to the log dialog, open the context menu on the dev branch and select delete branch and open the context menu on the `master` branch and create a new branch called `dev`).

Answer (score 0):

I have *no* idea if this is right or wrong, but I seem to have overwritten another branch with master like this:

```
git push origin master:otherbranch
```

And then when I switched I had to pull, and it was good to go?

Comment: Hmm.. Well, it worked for me. I did not have any other person using the git repo though.

Comment: Not really helpful that whoever downvoted your answer didn't bother to write a comment explaining why. :/

Comment: I agree, and they seem to be multiplying :D maybe it's because the OP actually wanted `TortoiseGIT` answer but I honestly doubt it just lets you overwrite a branch like this.

Comment: I was downvoting the culture around this Q&A format.  Noisy discussion, posting answers that start with "I have no idea..."  

The answer truly is useful, regardless if it applies to tortoisegit, but this overall format of noise around git commands that really beg for clarification is not a strength of git-related stack-overflow Q&A

Comment: I won't say I know its exact effects if I don't. I also won't advertise it that way.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce For the record (sorry to dig up old posts), the command you typed is overwriting the branch named `otherbranch` *on the remote repo* with the local version of `master`. In OP's case, he would have needed something along the lines of `git push origin master:dev` then `git checkout dev && git pull`